# Calculate Distance of Data per IndexPath from different Class

Tags: swift, uitableview, cllocationmanager

I try to calculate the Distance between the user and a location of any cell's given Data from another class, so I can reuse the Cells... calculating the distance from the TableViewCellClass itself worked, but as soon as I scrolled the tableVIew, the Result of the Distance changed all the time.

My CalculateDistance Class:

```
class CalculateDistance: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate{
    
    var reloading:Reloading?
    let location = CLLocationManager()
    var job: Job!
    var Distance: String = ""
    static var gettingDistance: String = ""

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let lastLocation = locations.last {
            let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
            //get job coordinates
            geocoder.geocodeAddressString(JobTableViewController.jobLocation) { placemarks, error in
                print(JobTableViewController.jobLocation)
                let placemarkW = placemarks?.first
                if let placemark = placemarkW {
                    let lat = placemark.location?.coordinate.latitude
                    let lon = placemark.location?.coordinate.longitude
                    let jobLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat!, longitude: lon!)
                    //get user coordinates
                    let myLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lastLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: lastLocation.coordinate.longitude)
                    //get distance between coordinates
                    let distance = myLocation.distance(from: jobLocation) / 1000
                    CalculateDistance.gettingDistance = String(format: "%.01fkm", distance)
                } else {
                    CalculateDistance.gettingDistance = "Not Valid"
                }
                self.reloading?.reloadIt()
            }
        }
        self.location.stopUpdatingLocation()
        guard let _: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
    }
    
}
```

And how I try to call it/print it in the tableViewClass:

```
static var jobLocation: String = ""
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "JobCell", for: indexPath) as! JobTableViewCell
    let job = jobs[indexPath.row]
    cell.job = job
    cell.jobHeader.text = job.postHeader
    cell.distance.text = CalculateDistance.gettingDistance
    return cell
}
```

The problem now is that the label text is blank... I tried printing the Distance itself inside the CalculateDistance class but this doesn't work either...

Comment: So, you have one place (`CalculateDistance.gettingDistance`) that stores a single distance, but potentially many cells that refer to this value? Plus, did you consider that the table cells may be rendered before your geocoding call finishes?

Comment: On the tactical observation, where do you set the delegate for the `CLLocationManager` and where do you request permission for location and where do you call [`startUpdatingLocation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423750-startupdatinglocation)? In the absence of that, `locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:)` will never be called.

Comment: Unrelated, on broader design, the `static` approach seriously constraints the usefulness of `CalculateDistance`. Also, if your user location changes, you really do not want to repeatedly geocode the same `jobLocation` string. Its coordinates haven’t changed. So, decouple the updating of the user location, from the geocoding of the job address, from the the calculation of the distance betwixt.

Comment: Very minor observation, but you can eliminate the “I’ve got a placemark with a `CLLocation` ... let me grab the `latitude` and `longitude` from its `coordinate` and then create a new `CLLocation` from those values” logic. Just use the `location` property of the placemark. Same with `myLocation`/`lastLocation`.